# javascript functions not supported by any browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla, netscape

Can anyone help me to list the JavaScript functions, which are not supported by any browser.
Ex:
Like   map()  function,this will supported in IE8
(you would have faced this type of problems in your development phases). i tried googling in documentation of browsers but i can't get it clearly.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://caniuse.com already does this for you by linking out to http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5

Comment: Please provide the code that doesn't work, together with your desired behaviour and its actual behaviour.

Comment: well, if any browser include lynx, then i'd say about all of them, and you can find holes in much more recent browsers, ie11 for example doesn't have getUserMedia() or SharedWorker()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RGraham commented

- [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/)
- [kangax.github.io](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/)

Also

- [pointedears.de](http://pointedears.de/scripts/test/es-matrix/)
- [robertnyman.com](http://robertnyman.com/javascript/)
- [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/)
- [compatibility.shwups-cms.ch](http://compatibility.shwups-cms.ch/en/home) - this is interesting

There is also a lib called [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) <sup>[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modernizr)</sup> intended to detect all available features of a browser. There is more useful information on the [github](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) page of the lib.